# Non-arithmetical proof of kernels decomposition lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Here is a well-known result in linear algebra :

> Let $E$ be a vector space over a field $K$. Let $P_1,\cdots,P_r\in K[X]$ satisfying $\text{gcd}(P_i,P_j)=1$ whenever $i\neq j$ and let $P=\prod_{i=1}^rP_i$. Then for every endomorphism $u\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ :
>   $$\ker(P(f))=\bigoplus_{i=1}^r\ker(P_i(f))$$

And here is a special case of that result :

> Let $E$ be a complex vector space, let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, $r\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$  and $Q\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $Q(\alpha)\neq 0$. Let $P=(X-\alpha)^rQ$. Then for every $u\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ :
>   $$\ker(P(f))=\ker((f-\alpha\,id_E)^r)\oplus\ker(Q(f))$$

I am looking for a proof of that special case, which would **avoid** any reference to any arithmetical properties of complex polynomials (such as gcd, Bezout theorem and so on...).

I do know how to do this when $r=1$ (proof below) and I would like to generalize this proof to any value of $r$, but *in the same spirit*.

Any hints would be welcome :)

---

**Proof when $r=1$ :**

Let $x\in\ker(P(f))$. Suppose $x=a+b$ with $a\in\ker(f-\alpha\,id_E)$ and $b\in\ker(Q(f))$. Whe have :
$$[Q(f)](x)=[Q(f)](a)=Q(\alpha)\,a$$Hence$$a=\frac{1}{Q(\alpha)}[Q(f)](x)$$and$$b=x-\frac{1}{Q(\alpha)}[Q(f)](x)$$
Conversely, if $a$ and $b$ are defined by the two previous formulas, then obviously :
\begin{eqnarray*}
x & = & a+b\\
(f-\alpha\,id_E)(a) & = & \frac{1}{Q(\alpha)}[P(f)](x)=0_E\\
[Q(f)](b) & = & [Q(f)](x)-[Q(f)](a)=[Q(f)](x)-Q(\alpha)\,a=0_E
\end{eqnarray*}
All this proves that :
$$\ker(P(f))\subset\ker((f-\alpha\,id_E)^r)\oplus\ker(Q(f))$$
and the missing inclusion is straightforward.